# Android apps stopped working with newest versions of PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, angularjs, phonegap-build, ngresource

I use PhoneGap to convert an AngularJS app to Android and iOS. I need to upgrade to the latest version of PhoneGap for iOS 9, but it breaks the Android app.

Specifically, it stops ngResource from working, so I can't get an authentication token from my server.

Android works fine with config.xml preference set to

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
```

Android fails to even send the request to the server with either of these

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
```

Here is my AngularJs login function and ngResource factory.

```
$scope.login = function () {
    AuthenticationService.get({
            'clientId':$rootScope.clientId,
            'clientSecret':$rootScope.clientSecret,
            'username':$scope.loginData.username,
            'password':$scope.loginData.password
        },
        function(data){},
        function(error){
            toastr.error('Authentication failed, please try again.');
        }
    )
    .$promise.then(function(response){
       ...
    });
};


.factory( 'AuthenticationService', function($resource, $rootScope) {
    return $resource(
        $rootScope.url+'/oauth/v2/token?client_id=:clientId&client_secret=:clientSecret&grant_type=password&username=:username&password=:password',
        {
            clientId:'@clientId',
            clientSecret:'@clientSecret',
            username:'@username',
            password:'@password'
        },
        {
            get: { method: 'JSONP', params: { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' }, isArray: false }
        }
    );
})
```

Does anyone know what has changed in the newer versions of PhoneGap for Android that could cause this?

Comment: Mike, your answer is waiting [on nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/the-newer-versions-of-phonegap-are-breaking-angularjs-resource-on-android#reply_16182463)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the `whitelist` plugin reference inside your config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```